# - Type 'GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory

Tags: android, firebase

Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').

- Type 'GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 46):

Upgrading google-services to 4.3.8 fixed this issue for me.

You can do this by replacing the existing version at build.graddle file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Update google-service dependency in project gradle

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

[image]